# Résumé section about myself

Tags: word-choice

What would I correct name the section of résumé where I describe myself? Word-for-word translation gave me “Personal properties”, but it feels like something is wrong.

**EDIT:**

Information in this section looks like:

- can work in team
- sociable
- don’t have harmful habits
- etc...

Not about my skills or interests, but about me as person.

Comment: "About me", "Background", "Introduction", etc.

Comment: personal properties sounds like the opposite of communal properties

Comment: "Personal" or "Interests" are also common in my part of the U.S.

Comment: How are you describing yourself?  I think the answer might be determined by the type of information you are including. Many of the answers above could be useful depending on the information.

Comment: @gbutters, have added to question example of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you plan to provide, *About Me* is best.